pytest_collection_modifyitems does not work in multithreaded test runs
I have a hook
def pytest_collection_modifyitems(items):       
     print('Hello')     `  
     print(len(items))

I run the tests with the command
pytest -v -m "test_hook" -n 3 test/integration --dist loadscope
but the hook doesn't work
there is no text output in the console
What am I doing wrong?
